# Disable touch buttons on Dell XPS 14?

Tags: dell-xps

I have one of the new [Dell XPS 14](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-14/pd.aspx) laptops running Windows 7 64-bit. The laptop has three touch buttons above the keyboard (Windows Mobility Center, customizable button, and audio settings). Here's a photo of the buttons:

[image: Dell XPS 14 Touch Buttons]

I keep touching them accidentally and it's become very annoying. Is there any way to disable them?

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't personally own that laptop but if worse comes to worst, you can delete the drivers for the touch buttons. However make sure you know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to disable two of them, on the right side.

1. Open the Start Menu
2. Type `msconfig`
3. In the "launch" tab find the QuickSet by Dell, uncheck it, apply and OK
4. Restart the machine, ignore the message / select do not show any more / hit OK.

Answer (score -2):

1. Click the Windows Start button, move your cursor up the Start menu,
   and pause over the  "Settings" line.
2. A popup menu should appear: click on its "Control Panel" item to
   open the Control Panel window.
3. In the Control Panel window, find the "Mouse" icon and double-click
   it.
4. In the Mouse window are various tabs that control your pointing
   devices and cursor settings. There should be some options here to
   disable your Touch Pad *or* your Track Stick.

Comment: It's not the touchpad I want to disable. It's the three touch buttons over the keyboard.

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall dell quickset.
Disable windows mobility in the running processes.